# Was Daniel a prophet?

Tags: nevua-prophecy

The book of Daniel is in the Ketuvim portion of Tanach, which would indicate him not being among the prophets.

However, Daniel was given the ability to interpret Nebuchadnezzar's dream
(Daniel 2:19)

> Then the secret was revealed to Daniel in the vision of the night; then Daniel blessed the God of heaven.

He also had his own prophetic-like dream and was able to interpret it (Daniel 7:1)

> In the first year of Belshazzar, the king of Babylon, Daniel saw a dream, and the visions of his mind [while asleep] on his bed; then he wrote the dream and said the beginnings of the matters.

It should be noted that these events happened during the night when he was asleep, like how Hashem speaks to other prophets.

**Is Daniel considered a prophet? If not, why?**

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C#%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90%D7%95_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94

Comment: The category "prophet" if correctly understood, would correspond to someone who introduces to humanity fundamental new insights. The language these individuals typically use involves speaking about "communication from God" or seeing visions in the night...if you understand the brilliant insights about the fundamental nature of reality which Daniel is communicating you will recognize without doubt it is appropriate to call him a prophet. The different manners in which insight is communicated (awake, asleep) are codewords the prophets use to delimit the scope of their new knowledge